# Rabbi Yishmael - why such a name?

Tags: names

Why did Rabbi Yishmael from the Mishna have such a name? Yishmael is obviously the ancestor of the muslims (Bnei Yishamel)
The reason Hagar called her son this is because G-D "heard" her prayer and the name itself has a nice meaning, although the Torah itself calls him a Pera Adam.
But I still dont understand why any Jew would use this name.

Also are there any Jews called Yishmael from later periods?

Comment: Muslims belong to a religion, not an ethnicity. And it's not universally accepted that Arabs are descendants of Yishmael.

Comment: There was also Yishmael Kohen Gadol, made popular in this Avraham Fried song lol https://youtu.be/V3sEjAl8vOM?si=-sAAsE9jO4znz87p&t=130

Answer (score 8):

[Ritva to Yoma 38b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.38b.4?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=Ritva&lang2=en) offers two explanations:

1. Yishmael [repented](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16b.16) and died a righteous man.
2. The name is special because it [came from Hashem](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.16.11?lang=bi).

Comment: You certainly know your Ritva, nice catch!

Comment: @RabbiKaii It's all google